# How to increase stored block states from 128 to 10 000 in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

AFAIK Geth preserves states for the last 128 blocks by default. I would like to keep states for, say 10000 blocks (not turning myself into archive node). Is it possible?

Comment: 128? I thought it was 1,000 .

Comment: Ethereum team has not yet solved the problem of pruning the state, once you sync your node, it will become an archival node from the block you joined the network

Comment: Is there a way to become full archive node (sync with all previous blocks as well) ?

Comment: you have to use geth 1.8 ,  pruning (supposedly) is now working in this version, but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the line number 60 in core/blockchain.go , by setting this constant:

```
triesInMemory       = 128
```

to 10,000

And... God bless you.

If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: what is the purpose of increasing this number for full-archive nodes?